# Configure ObjectMapper globally (via @Bean or smth) to parse from "data" node

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapper

There have been thousands of jackson questions on SO and other resources, I've spent several hours already in searching, but still can't figure it out.

I'm trying to consume a REST web-service, it returns info in usual single object json format like:

```
{
  "data" : { SomeData },
  "meta: : {MetaInfo}
}
```

or with arrays :

```
{
  "data" : [ {SomeData}, {SomeData} ],
  "meta: : {MetaInfo}
}
```

SomeData is some POJO class, which I need to parse. There a dozens of different POJO classes in the service. I don't care about `MetaInfo` for now, but I suppose the solution to my problem will help to deal with it as well.

I want to use a single POJO class per each `SomeData` type to handle both responses with single object and with arrays. And the problem is in this `data` node that I should start parsing from.

**Question**: is there a possibility to configure globally my `ObjectMapper` to parse only info from `data` node?

SO, I want smth like this:

```
SomeData data = new ObjectMapper().fromNode("data").readValue(inputString, SomeData.class);
```

or with array:

```
List<SomeData> listData = new ObjectMapper().fromNode("data").readValue(inputString, new TypeReference<List<SomeData>>() {});
```

There's a workaround, of course - to use `wrapper` objects that contain `data` node and `List<SomeData>` like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SomeDataWrapper  {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<SomeData> data;

    public List<SomeData> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

but it's an overhead from my point of view. So, I basically should have twice as many classes as needed + overhead in taking out those lists out of wrapper classes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT1:**

I'd like to globally config `ObjectMapper` to look for `data` node. I'm using Spring `RestTemplate` and it handles deserializing underneath when calling e.g. `restTemplate.exchange(..)` method. So I'd like to delegate it to Spring, not wanting to manually parse each endpoints response using JsonNode / traversing through response data.

**EDIT2:**
I know I can define a `@Bean` with jackson's `Module` and register custom deserializers, but again I'd need to define a new deserializer class per each POJO. This will be a great pain and boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize the JSON as a `TreeNode`  with `ObjectMapper.readTree(String)` and select the path to map such as :

```
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(inputString)
                                  .path("data");
```

Then map the `JsonNode` to a `SomeData` array with `ObjectMapper.treeToValue(TreeNode, Class)`:

```
 SomeData[] data = jsonObjectMapper.treeToValue(node, SomeData[].class);
```

Comment: Good hint, I didn't know this approach, thanks! However, I'd like to globally config `ObjectMapper` to look for `data` node. I'm using Spring RestTemplate and it handles deserializing underneath when calling e.g. `restTemplate.exchange(..)` method. So I'd like to delegate it to Spring, not wanting to manually parse each endpoints response. Is it possible? Added to question

Comment: You are welcome :) I don't see how you could easily generalize the deserializing for a set of classes without specifying a deserializer for each class. But you are not constraint to create a different for each one. You could parameterize it with the class you need. Besides to avoid maintaining  the setup you could introduce a custom annotation that you add add on the classes and add a config processing that at startup instantiate a deserializer for each annotated class. It should not be very hard to write.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way that this is possible assuming you want to use the same exact property name `data` to contain multiple different *TYPES* of data (Object | Array).

I would suggest this is a very poor design choice on the API providers side, if you have any ability to change this, changing it to ALWAYS return a list, which could be of size `1` would be much more ideal.

Other than that, I don't know of any way to tell the `ObjectMapper` that the type of `data` is *either* `Foo` *or* `List<Foo>`.

Comment: I think it makes sense in some way - to separate `important` data from `metaInfo` like plan subscription or response timestamp. I cannot change response in any way. But if  I can configure `mapper` to grab `data` nodes I can simply specify desired output (object / Array) depending on endpoint

Comment: Sorry, but your'e still stuck with the fact that `typeof SomeData` !=  `typeof List<SomeData>`. There isn't going to be a way to tell the object mapper to "Try to Deserialize it as an object, and then if that doesn't work, try it as a List" as that's the only way this could be accomplished

Comment: I can do it depending on endpoint. With the help of `new TypeReference<List<SomeData>>() {})` or `SomeData.class` - I know which endpoint returns what kind of data

Comment: It's also possible with custom deserializers - we analize `data` node and whether it's  an array or not - produce object or an array

Comment: Sure, if you're programmatically doing it, of course. But I don't see any way you could configure the global ObjectMapper to do so unless you use the wrapper class as you specify above.